# How to blank out and read complete AnyOfferChangeNotification in SQS?

Tags: push-notification, amazon-sqs, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

As anyofferschange notification amount varies with time. We don't have any specific way to read multiple notifications together.

So, I am reading one by one and saving some of information in sql server database, It takes quite a lot of time that I can never finish reading all the notifications.

What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did...I started by clearing out the queue.  Then I started my windows service that every few seconds polled the queue.  I think I pulled back 10 messages at time.  I would get a total count of messages and then spin up a number of threads that could handle the amount of messages I had waiting.  One by one, I read the message, add to my SQL database, then delete the message from SQS.

Over time, I understood better how many threads to spin up and how often to poll my queue.  As long as my service was running, I would maintain just a handful of SQS messages in the queue at a time and I would quickly read and process them.   Occasionally, due to bad programming (yeah, it happens), my service would crash and I wouldn't know about it.  Tens of thousands of messages become queued up and I would put my service in "crisis" mode, which polled at an increasing rate and essentially maxed out the number of calls I could make to SQS.  Usually in a few hours, my service would catch up and then I increase the polling interval.  Sometimes though, I would just dump the queue and start over as I'd have potentially hundreds of price changes on a single SKU and didn't want to waste the processing time to go through them.  But most of the time, things ran smoothly.

Why can't you read more than one notification together?  Like I said, I believe I read 10 at a time on each thread.  Once I got the 10 messages, I processed them in a loop and dumped them to a SQL database.  Once the 10 were processed, I send a message up to SQS to delete.

I ran this for several years on an account with over 10,000 SKU's.  We had up to the minute price change notifications on all our products and could instantly reprice and update Amazon, if needed.

Comment: How do you ensure multiple thread should not read duplicate notification?

Comment: You'd set the visibility timeout so that once read, they are marked invisible for xx seconds and another thread can't access them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html